# Terminology - Cache (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, terminology

I have watched a couple videos on JavaScript where the presenter mentioned "caching" a variable but I didn't see them do anything in the code that would "cache" it beyond normal assignments. When I think of cache I think of something stored in local memory in which case aren't all JavaScript variables cached by definition.

When you cache a variable in JavaScript what are you "doing" to it?

EDIT:
I have heard the term in several but the only one that comes to mind is [Writing Modular JavaScript - Tutorial](http://marketplace.tutsplus.com/item/writing-modular-javascript/128103/?ref=addyosmani). Which I just watched last night. I didn't post it because you have to pay to view and I hate feeling liking I am plugging a pay service on StackExchange.

Comment: If you want us to discuss the content of some videos, you should post links to them.

Comment: @user16764 I added a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/efficientjs.shtml) on efficient javascript:

> One of the best kept secrets to boosting script performance is to
>   cache your objects. Often times, your script will repeatedly access a
>   certain object, as in the following demonstration:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> for (i=0;i<document.images.length;i++)
> document.images[i].src="blank.gif"
> </script>
> ```
>
> In the above, the object "document.images" is what's accessed multiple
>   times. **The code to realizing it is inefficient, since the browser must
>   dynamically look up "document.images" twice during each loop** (once to
>   see if `i<document.images`, and the other, to access and change the
>   image's `src`). If you have 10 images on the page, for example, that's
>   20 calls to the Images object right there. Excessive calls to
>   JavaScript objects can wear down the browser, not to mention your
>   computer's memory.
>
> The term "cache your object" means storing a repeatedly access object
>   inside a user defined variable, and using that variable instead in
>   subsequent references to the object. The performance improvement can
>   be significant. Here's a modified version of the initial script using
>   object caching:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var theimages=document.images
> for (i=0;i<theimages.length;i++)
> theimages[i].src="blank.gif"
> </script>
> ```
>
> **Not only is the number of times document.images[] is referenced cut in
>   half** with the above, but for each time it is referenced, the browser
>   doesn't have to go through document.images first, but goes straight to
>   its containing array.
>
> Remember to use object caching when calling highly nested DHTML
>   objects, like document.all.myobject, or document.layers.firstlayer
>   etc.

and

> **some JavaScript objects are less forgiving on the browser than others.**
>   While recognizing exactly which isn't easy (and isn't the goal here),
>   just becoming aware of this fact is important.
>
> Take, for example, these two properties:
>
> ```
> -object.innerText //IE only
> -object.innerHTML
> ```
>
> Did you know that the second property demands multiple times the
>   system resources to call than the first? If all you're changing is the
>   textual content of a `<div>` or `<span>` and in IE only, `innerText` would
>   definitely be the more efficient choice. Another example are the CSS
>   properties "`display`" and "`visibility`"; the former is significantly
>   more expensive than the later.

With JavaScript object caching, the number of lookups is cutdown, since the object reference is held within the variable - potentially improving performance and memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) can help you figure out which kinds of references to your data get garbage collected at which point, with more detailed discussion [here](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) and elsewhere on the web.

When you're looking to keep data in local memory in javascript, you'll want to make sure you store a reference to it that stays in scope for as long as it's required. This will require that you make some assignments at some point - sometimes using local variables ( ie: var x = cached value), though, more likely, you'll want to place things onto longer lived objects,ie:

```
jQuery.extend(myObject, {
   dog_cacher: []
}

...

myObject.dog_cacher = ["brown dog", "spotted dog"]
```